# How do I get all the files from all the Directories, inside other Directores and check for each file size?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
          for (int i = 0; i < BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories.Count; i++)
            {
                 file_array =Directory.GetFiles(BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories[i]);
            }

            DateTime[] creationTimes8 = new DateTime[file_array.Length];


              for (int i = 0; i < file_array.Length; i++)
                creationTimes8[i] = new FileInfo(file_array[i]).CreationTime;
            Array.Sort(creationTimes8, file_array);
            file_indxs = 0;
            file_indxs = file_array.Length - 1;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
```

urlsDirectories contain 5 directories in which you have a  directory on each index.
In each directory there are some files. I have a string Array file_array. The Array I get, file_array at the end of the loop only contains the last directory file and not all the files. I need all the files in that specific directory.

Once that is done, I need to check if the file sizes are greater than 0, and if It is satisfying the condition then continue on.

EDIT** this is the timer1 tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {     
                //this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                if (leave == true)
                {
                    pb.Load(file_array[file_indxs]);
                }
                else
                {
                    pbs[0].Load(file_array[file_indxs]);
                }
                file_indxs = file_indxs - 1;
                if (file_indxs < 0)
                {
                    file_indxs = file_array.Length - 1;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the files with size greater than 0 for all directories into a `List`:

```
List<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = new List<System.IO.FileInfo>();
for (int i = 0; i < BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories.Count; i++)
{
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories[i]);
    fileList.AddRange(di.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => x.Length > 0));
}
```

Now `fileList` will contain the list of `FileInfo` which you can use further in your code.

Please note that I used `System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories` to search in all subdirectories as well - I'm not sure if you need it or not.

---

You can use the following code to sort the list of files by creation date and convert it to a array of file names:

```
String[] file_array = fileList.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
```

If you want to sort in the descending order, you can use

```
String[] file_array = fileList.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime).Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
```

Comment: Syzmon and how do i use this List now with the rest of my code ? In the rest of my code i used file_array that is string[] but now i have a List. The rest of the code above with the DateTime and loop under it..

Comment: What do you do with the rest of the code? It's a bit unclear. You just sort it by creation time?

Comment: Szymore i just updated my question now to show you what im doing with it later. Im using it in timer1 tick event to show/display the images/files in a pictureBox like animation. Thats why i sort it so it will animate it from the first file. But before i used the file_array that is string[]

Comment: Szymon its working but its starting from the last to the first. At least on the images i see the date and time and the animation move to the wrong side. So how do i make it to start from the first to the last ? maybe the sort should be something else and not creationtime ?

Comment: Strange in the file_array the files are from the first to the end but in the pictureBox the animation start from the end. and move to the other way.

Comment: Something in my timer1 tick event im doing wrong that make it mvoe the other way i think.

Comment: How do i get the beginning of the array instead the end ? In my timer tick event i did: file_indxs = file_indxs + 1;
                if (file_indxs <= 0)
                {
                    file_indxs = file_array.Length - 1;
                } but file_array.Length - 1 give the end of the array. How do i make that the file_indxs will start from the beginning of the array and then move up each time by 1 ?

Comment: Szymon its working now but i think it was better to fix it from the timer tick event the code there then reverse the array.

Comment: Let's leave it at that then. If you have more problems, please post separate questions. Stack Overflow works best if you ask one question on one specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a recursive function that gets the files from a directory.

```
void GetFiles(string directory, ref List<string> directories)
{
    var tempFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory);
    var tempDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory);
    foreach (var x in tempFiles)
        directories.Add(x);
    foreach (var x in tempDirs)
        GetFiles(x, ref directories);
}
```

This would obtain all the files from a folder and its subfolders. You can then obtain the data for the files you have enumerated.